# Add a user specified number to a number already in a file. (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this could be a stupid question but I can't seem to actually do it.

I'm trying to do this:

```
f = open("txtfiles/c.txt", "r")
c = f.read()
int(c)
ca = float(input("Enter Cash to Add: "))
int(ca)
cn= c+ca
print (cn)
```

I have tried to say they are both floats so that they can be added properly because I need the user to be able to add decimals but when ever I do it I get
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly

I have searched on the internet and I have seen this error come up loads but nothing has actually seemed to help.

Sorry for the noob question but any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Please indent/format the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `int(c)` this will generate a integer from the string `c` but you don't assign it to anything. In your case `c` will still be a string. Change that line to:

```
    c = int(c)
```

Even better, since you want to get decimals added too why not just use floats and skip the integer conversion?

```
    f = open("txtfiles/c.txt", "r")
    c = float(f.read())
    ca = float(input("Enter Cash to Add: "))
    cn = c + ca
    print cn
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
with open("txtfiles/c.txt", "rU") as f:
    cn=float(f.read())+float(raw_input("Enter Cash to Add: "))
    print(cn)
```

Using [`with`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) will automagically close your file on block exit, so you don't accidently leave it open. Using `'rU'` as file mode will handle [newline madness](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) for you.

Comment: (had to change a couple things so it will actually work with 3.2)
I tried using